# Selenium Error Missing or invalid capabilities

Tags: python, linux, selenium

```
  File "/root/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 270, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 363, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 428, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created exception: Missing or invalid capabilities
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 5.15.0-46-generic x86_64)
```

With even a simple selenium script, it gives this error... I can't find anything on what it means, Help!

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the code that reproduces this error?

Answer (score 1):

If your chrome browser is recently updated then you might get this error. The solution for this problem is simply to update your chrome driver.

 Choose chrome driver from the below link that will suit your system architecture.

 [Click here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/)

Remove the older chromedriver from your path, Update your chromedriver with lastest version. And please clarify your question.